# Magento 1.9: Sql setup Stripe module not execute

Tags: magento-1.9, module, sql, setup-script

I'm installing throught composer the Stripe module, the problem is that when I installed the site, where the module work, crash because can't find the table in Database.
I don't know why the setup sql file did't excecute.

The error is `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '.stripe_webhooks' doesn't exist`

But the module has the script inside the file: stripe/app/code/community/Stripe/Payments/sql/stripe_payments_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable($installer->getTable('stripe_customers'))
```

When is online, the module is working because it crash without finding the table, but the script above it doesn't running.

Is there something that I miss?

Answer (score 0):

**Another way to install**

You can simply download zip file from below link as per your need

https://github.com/stripe-archive/stripe-magento1-releases

Comment: Thank you, but I had the composer for successive update with new release using pipeline for deploy on server

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the module was already installed in the past. Check in table `core_resource` if you found `stripe`, and delete the `stripe` row to restart all scripts.

Be carefull, do not delete all rows, you will crash your website.

Comment: Thank you, in staging I checked the same line and I saw the table had the code_resouce, I don't know about that delete that line restart all script.
I solved importing the table on the production database, because the module wasn't installed on production until composer was update.